# How can I change ActiveControl properties using vba Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created this sub to do some formatting depending on `ActiveControl` `CommandButton`

```vb
Sub ReFormat(Sender As CommandButton)
    'Me.PictureBox.Picture = Me.Controls(Sender).Picture
    Me.PictureBox.Picture = Sender.Picture
    Me.lbl.Caption = Sender.Caption
    Sender.PictureCaptionArrangement = acRight
    Sender.FontBold = True
    Sender.ForeColor = RGB(45, 48, 60)
End Sub
```

And called it from :

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    ReFormat (ActiveControl)
End Sub
```

It throws this error

[image]

I tried this

```vb
Sub ReFormat(Sender As Object)
Sub ReFormat(Sender As Control)
```

Still the same .

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *parenthesis* makes it read-only. Try:

```
ReFormat ActiveControl
```

Comment: It's not that the parentheses make this read-only, it is that *without a Call statement* they force VBA to try to evaluate what is inside them and send that value on to the sub.  Command buttons cannot be evaluated this way so you get the 438 error. Get into the habit of always using Call with your subroutines.  This will force you to use parentheses BUT the call will always be made by reference - e.g. Call Reformat(ActiveControl) will work just fine here.

Comment: @deluxeinformation: It is. If having used the deprecated Call syntax, the question would have read `Call ReFormat((ActiveControl))` which, likewise, wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @Gustav, I'm not sure I understand your comment but am hoping to learn something.  First I'm not aware that Call is deprecated, although many people don't like to use it.  And I don't understand your reference to "Call ReFormat((ActiveControl))" with doubled parentheses.  But I stand by my declaration that Call ReFormat(ActiveControl) is equivalent to Reformat ActiveControl and that Reformat(ActiveControl) without Call fails before control ever passes to sub Reformat().

Comment: @deluxeinformation: Issue is, that the argument - `Sender` - must be passed `ByRef` for `Reformat` to work as intended. That's not possible if you wrap it in parenthesis. Then, wether you use the one syntax, `Reformat x`, or the other, `Call Reformat(x)`, doesn't matter. Using parenthesis is not a "bad thing"; if the argument is an array, that will cast the data type - see for example my function `Decrypt` [here](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Cryptography/blob/main/BCrypt.bas) where variable `Key` is wrapped in line 787: `If DecryptData(EncryptedData, (Key), TextData) = True Then`.